# Finding the schema type of Freebase type in MQL

Tags: freebase, mql

Anyone know how to get the type of an expected type ?

For example, the "/people/person" type has a property called "/people/person/places_lived" which has an expected type of "/people/place_lived"

The problem is, I'm trying to figure out what type "/people/place_lived" is using MQL. I know "/people/place_lived" is a Mediator type, but I'm trying to figure out what the MQL is to find out that its a mediator type when I only have one piece of information (eg: "/people/place_lived")

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to ask MQL for the `/freebase/type_hints/mediatory` property of that type: [see example](http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor/?q=%7B%22id%22%3a%22/people/place_lived%22,%22/freebase/type_hints/mediator%22%3anull%7D&autorun=1).

```
{
  "id" :"/people/place_lived",
  "/freebase/type_hints/mediator" : null
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably get a quicker/better answer on the Freebase mailing list, but I think the main distinguishing characteristic of a Mediator or CVT type is that it doesn't include the type "/common/topic"

```
[{
  "id":"/people/place_lived",
  "/freebase/type_hints/included_types":[]
}]​
```

versus

```
[{
  "id":"/people/person",
  "/freebase/type_hints/included_types":["/common/topic"]
}]​
```

A good way to poke around is to use the Inspect pages and compare two things to see how they are the same or different http://www.freebase.com/inspect/people/person

One thing which makes this a little trickier is that, as its name implies, this is just an internal hint and it's used as a "naked property" ie doesn't have the corresponding type applied with it.

The presence of /common/topic is what triggers most of the UI visible differs, but depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to look at some other characteristics (e.g. nodes which link only to primitive data elements vs those that link to other nodes).

Comment: Thx Tom, however other types such as "/government/us_president" dont have a /common/topic/ type but arent CVT types either. On the Freebase page http://www.freebase.com/schema/people/place_lived  , they list it as a Mediator type, so they must be pulling it from some where.

Answer (score 0):

Look for /freebase/type_hints/mediator -- it's a boolean property which will be true if the type is a CVT.  You can see an example here: http://www.freebase.com/inspect/people/marriage